# Failed to destroy regular DB in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I found lots of "IO error" in tserver's ERROR log:

```
E0622 18:12:44.155575 460196 tablet_metadata.cc:400] Failed to destroy regular DB at: /home/yugabyte/data/yb-data/tserver/data/rocksdb/table-00004200000030008000000000004254/tablet-71c67832a05b4effa7462823983c7e6a: IO error (yb/rocksdb/util/env_posix.cc:317): /home/yugabyte/data/yb-data/tserver/data/rocksdb/table-00004200000030008000000000004254/tablet-71c67832a05b4effa7462823983c7e6a/LOCK: No such file or directory
E0622 18:12:44.158552 460196 tablet_metadata.cc:400] Failed to destroy regular DB at: /home/yugabyte/data/yb-data/tserver/data/rocksdb/table-000042000000300080000000000042e4/tablet-ac80c3319e784abaa9eb93d6caca6faf: IO error (yb/rocksdb/util/env_posix.cc:317): /home/yugabyte/data/yb-data/tserver/data/rocksdb/table-000042000000300080000000000042e4/tablet-ac80c3319e784abaa9eb93d6caca6faf/LOCK: No such file or directory
E0622 18:12:44.163367 460196 tablet_metadata.cc:400] Failed to destroy regular DB at: /home/yugabyte/data/yb-data/tserver/data/rocksdb/table-000042000000300080000000000042b7/tablet-c156f2fc85154a4c8d835660aa1c5244: IO error (yb/rocksdb/util/env_posix.cc:317): /home/yugabyte/data/yb-data/tserver/data/rocksdb/table-000042000000300080000000000042b7/tablet-c156f2fc85154a4c8d835660aa1c5244/LOCK: No such file or directory
E0622 18:12:44.166888 460196 tablet_metadata.cc:400] Failed to destroy regular DB at: /home/yugabyte/data/yb-data/tserver/data/rocksdb/table-0000420000003000800000000000420c/tablet-48c3441b5a6f469c99407b8cc04b7d26: IO error (yb/rocksdb/util/env_posix.cc:317): /home/yugabyte/data/yb-data/tserver/data/rocksdb/table-0000420000003000800000000000420c/tablet-48c3441b5a6f469c99407b8cc04b7d26/LOCK: No such file or directory
```

I have checked disk and network,  both of them work fine.
I can create/drop/select/update/insert through psql too.

Can I ignore these errors, or anything I can do to follow this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these logs only generated after tserver started, without repeating and everything works fine you can ignore them.